# can not find unexpected undentifier in mongo db export query

Tags: mongodb

I am writing this query in mongo shell

```
mongoexport --db database_name --collection collection_name --out filename.json
```

query to export but the error is

```
SyntaxError: unexpected identifier
```

can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoexport is a terminal command line utility to export data, not mongoshell functional directive.
Try running the same in terminal.

```
$ mongoexport --db database_name --collection collection_name --out filename.json
```

Make sure you have all the utilities that come with mongo added to your path.